# Ompl ros calling the joint space planner

Tags: ros, joint, ompl, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to call the joint space planner based on this tutorial :http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Calling%20the%20joint%20space%20planner. But I found error message.  I am testing on Ros Fuerte Ubuntu Precise 12.04. Thank you in  advance.

rosrun example_ompl_tutorials ompl_joint_goal
[ERROR] [1368075318.464256387]: Service call failed: service [/ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path] responded with an error: Tried to insert a message with time less than ros::MIN_TIME
[ERROR] [1368075318.464425236]: Motion planning failed oo nooooe
[ INFO] [1368075318.503725926]: Joint state monitor active
[ INFO] [1368075318.505195437]: Waiting for subscriber
[ INFO] [1368075318.855446888, 493.101000000]: Publishing path for display

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62434/ompl-ros-calling-the-joint-space-planner/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2013-05-09**:
I can execute that example without error. Copy the error message to help you better. Because as you put, just say you have a mistake, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can execute that example without error.
Copy the error message to help you better. Because as you put, just say you have a mistake, nothing more

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) with karma: 70 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-05-09**:
Thanks for the respond. the error is saying :[ERROR] [1368147736.105421840]: Motion planning failed, and the pr2 simulation on rviz does'nt move. when I try execute another example : rosrun rviz_display_trajectory_tutorial rviz_display_trajectory, the robot moves successfully. any idea?

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-05-14**:
I managed to execute it, but first I need to execute another code from pr2 package, move_arm_joint_goal and then execute the ompl_joint_goal. Thanks.